# How to parse xml content more than 8096 length

Tags: android, handler, xmlreader, saxparser

I'm trying to parse an xml file. 
It is gps coords.
So there is a string with latitude coords and with longtitude
You can imagine the size of the string(for example over 29k chars)
When i trying to parse it, I have a problem it parses only 8096.  I put a breakpoint in `characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)` and length only 8096.
I've tried to set bigger buffer to xmlreader, maybe trouble with input source. Or saxparser can handle only such length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation of saxparser is that it calls characters() many times if string is more than ~8k chars.parsing each part.
So you need just use not string for storing data, but StringBuffer or somethin like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your own class that implements `XmlPullParser`. You can then simply override the methods that read from the Reader. 
You can find something about `XmlPullParser` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

Comment: Can i do this using saxparser?